# How to remove "Open in terminal" option in right click

Tags: software-installation, nautilus

Iv installed Ubuntu-GNOME and immediately after that as an old habit I tried to add "Open in terminal" Option in my right click menu. By using

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

and

```
nautilus -q
```

But then I realized that I already have this option in my right click menu, And now I dont know how can I disable `nautilus-open-terminal`. I searched *nautilus* in my softwares but I found nothing.

also tried to use

```
apt-get --purge remove nautilus-open-terminal
```

But I faced this error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

How can I fix my Right-Click menu?

Answer (score 5):

Just use the command `apt-get --purge remove nautilus-open-terminal` with `sudo`

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nautilus-open-terminal
```

This is because some commands require administrative privileges to run, and `sudo` can give you that. Just be careful that you know what the command is for, when you're using `sudo` along with it.

Answer (score 1):

For the error:

> E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are
>   you root?

Are you root?

it seem you miss to use `sudo` so just run the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-open-terminal
```

Then run:

```
nautilus -q
```